# How to create different types of IDs in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create **Employee** table which have different types of Employees (ex: Salaried Employees, Hired Employees.)

***So, what is the best idea?***
Should i made 2 columns for ID (ex: id, type) in which *id* can take INT values and *type* can take either (S for Salaried Employee, H for Hired Employee.)
***Or***
Is there any way to create as such IDs (ex: S1, S2, ..., H6, H7,...)?

Comment: This depends on what you want to do.  In particular, do you want to use the ids for foreign key relationships?  If you don't understand the question, simply add in a `type` column in the `Employee` table.

Comment: yes i need to use the IDs for many to many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i made 2 columns for ID

IMO, **NO.**

Instead, you should have a column says `EMP_TYPE`, which tell the type of employee.

Imagine, you created two columns, then one column will always be useless for `Salaried` or `Hired` employee.

Comment: Is there any way to create as such IDs (ex: S1, S2, ..., H6, H7,...)?

Comment: @M.Sherif This can be done using trigger or do it from programming side